# Is Scrapy compatible with Python 3 on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Is 'scrapy' compatible with Python 3(or later) on Windows?
If not, then is the only option to use it with Python 2.7?
I need this for a project I need to do.
Thank you.

Comment: According to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Scrapy/1.3.3 Scrapy 1.3.3 supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.3+

Comment: Scrapy is compatible with Python 3 on Windows. Though [it's recommended to use Anaconda/Miniconda](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy runs on Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 or above.

> Scrapy is being ported to Python 3 using the single-codebase approach.
>   The goal is to make Scrapy work in both Python 2.7 and 3.3+ using the
>   six library to smooth differences between Python 2.x and 3.x.

[Installing scrapy in Windows 64 bit.](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/wiki/How-to-Install-Scrapy-0.14-in-a-64-bit-Windows-7-Environment)

You can check this site to use scrappy Python 3 in pycharm :

http://www.jianshu.com/p/54c906b18a42

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, you can install it via

`pip install scrapy`

(You may want to activate your virtual environment first)